# Index issue PLSQL Oracle. Using substring in index

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I need to join 2 tables and not sure how to use the index efficiently

Table 1 has the following index: `nvl(Member_ID,'NA')`

Table 2 has the following index: `Member_ID`

I can't just use the query of:

```
select * from table 1 A
join table 2 B on nvl(A.Member_ID,'NA') = B.Member_ID
```

because the format of `Member_ID` is different in both tables.
Table A `Member_ID` can have space at the end or extra characters like '123 00' and '123 01'
and Table B `Member_ID` will only have the first 3 digits. But the 1st 3 characters indicate that this is the same member

I can't really `join on substr(nvl(A.Member_ID,'NA'),0,3) = B.Member_ID` because that will eliminate the index. I am dealing with millions of records. Is there a way around this?

Comment: If you create index for `nvl ...` you can create index for `substr(nvl(A.Member_ID,'NA'),0,3)` too

Comment: I am just an user, not a developer. I can't create an index..

Comment: Then you can't do anything else. To fix Index problem you have to create or modify index.

Comment: Fixing the data model should also be a high priority.  A column where the first three characters indicate a member but that has additional stuff at the end but is still called `member_id` violates the most basic rules of proper database design and normalization.  Adding a function-based index is a nice work-around but working around a poor design is rarely a solid long-term solution.

Comment: The IT team is not willing to do a change for this. That's why I am hitting a roadblock here. Any other ways to do this....?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle allows function-based indexes.  So, you can define an index such as:

```
create index idx_table1_mid3 on table1(coalesce(substr(member_id, 1, 3), 'NA'));
```

Then, assuming that `table2.MemberId` is a string, Oracle can take advantage of the index.  If it is not a string, then the type conversion might prevent the usage of the computed index.

Note:  the `join` condition has to be specified as in the index:

```
on coalesce(substr(Member_Id, 1, 3), 'NA') = b.Member_Id
```

Comment: I do not have the privilege to create index... I am just an user. Will this still work?

Comment: If you cannot create an index, then creating an index will not work.